# cx_Oracle: DLL load failed

Tags: python, oracle, cx-oracle

I'm trying to `import cx_Oracle` in Python and getting an:

```
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified procedure could not be found.
```

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24124110/cx-oracle-dll-load-failed) suggests that there's a mismatch between the bits of cx_Oracle and the Oracle Client, but I don't believe that's the case in my situation. I downloaded cx_Oracle for 64-bit Python 3.5 from the [Unofficial Windows Binaries page](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/) and have confirmed that the 64-bit install of Oracle is the first one on my `PATH` (I also have a 32-bit copy, but it comes after). I am using the "standard" Oracle package FWIW, not the Instant Client. Also, I have 11g Oracle but the only available binary of cx_Oracle was 12c. Will that make a difference?

Answer (score 2):

I've had a few DLL Load failures myself when trying to use cx_Oracle (also using 11g).

1. I've fixed it by downloading **instant_client-basic (12)**.
   (I assume you're using windows.) 
   If you use Linux, there will be
   some environemnt variables you are going to need to change (you can
   find all about it here
   https://blogs.oracle.com/opal/entry/configuring_python_cx_oracle_and).
2. I don't know why did you download cx_Oracle from that unofficial website, but I'd give the official Python's website, https://pypi.python.org/pypi/cx_Oracle, a try.

   Hope This helps.

Comment: Thanks for the pointers - unfortuantely I can't (easily) change the Oracle client because this is a production server in active use. The reason I downloaded the binary from the "unofficial" website is because cx_Oracle does not compile natively on Windows. You either have to install Visual Studio (which wasn't working for me), or get a wheel file.

Comment: The Python cx_Oracle maintainer uploads Windows binaries to https://pypi.python.org/pypi/cx_Oracle as mentioned by @Maorg

Comment: Yea, indeed. @Jura If you enter the link, you can see the under the 'Type' section you could choose 'MS Windows Installer' type of Installer. 
Try downloading and installing it.

Comment: Glad this answer was useful. :)